# Random Npgsql Connection Timeout in .net6 Application

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, npgsql, connection-pool

I have this piece of code in program.cs to initialize my pool with 5 connections in my .net6 application using postgres and Npgsql.

```
List<NpgsqlConnection> connections = new List<NpgsqlConnection>();

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{

    NpgsqlConnection connection = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionString);
    try
    {
        connection.Open(); // This actually opens the connection

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        continue;
    }

    connections.Add(connection);
}
connections.ForEach(connection => { connection.Close(); });
```

the first attempt to creata a connection is always falis with a timeout

```
2024-01-11T19:54:53.7699503+09:00 40000374-0003-fc00-b63f-84710c7967bb [INF] Entity Framework Core "6.0.19" initialized '"DbContextClass"' using provider '"Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL":"6.0.8"' with options: "CommandTimeout=15 " (d2805559)
2024-01-11T19:55:09.4702152+09:00 40000374-0003-fc00-b63f-84710c7967bb [ERR] An error occurred using the connection to database '"my_db"' on server '""'. (5fc3407c)
2024-01-11T19:55:09.5272113+09:00 40000374-0003-fc00-b63f-84710c7967bb [INF] A transient exception occurred during execution. The operation will be retried after 0ms."
""System.TimeoutException: The operation has timed out.
   at Npgsql.Util.NpgsqlTimeout.Check()
   at Npgsql.Util.NpgsqlTimeout.CheckAndGetTimeLeft()
   at Npgsql.Util.NpgsqlTimeout.CheckAndApply(NpgsqlConnector connector)
   at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.<Open>g__OpenCore|195_1(NpgsqlConnector conn, SslMode sslMode, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean isFirstAttempt)
   at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.Open(NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.ConnectorPool.OpenNewConnector(NpgsqlConnection conn, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.ConnectorPool.<Get>g__RentAsync|28_0(NpgsqlConnection conn, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.<Open>g__OpenAsync|45_0(Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternalAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternalAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(AsyncEnumerator enumerator, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass33_0`2.<<ExecuteAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy.ExecuteImplementationAsync[TState,TResult](Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, TState state, CancellationToken cancellationToken)" (43386701)
System.TimeoutException: The operation has timed out.
   at Npgsql.Util.NpgsqlTimeout.Check()
   at Npgsql.Util.NpgsqlTimeout.CheckAndGetTimeLeft()
   at Npgsql.Util.NpgsqlTimeout.CheckAndApply(NpgsqlConnector connector)
   at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.<Open>g__OpenCore|195_1(NpgsqlConnector conn, SslMode sslMode, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean isFirstAttempt)
   at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.Open(NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.ConnectorPool.OpenNewConnector(NpgsqlConnection conn, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.ConnectorPool.<Get>g__RentAsync|28_0(NpgsqlConnection conn, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.<Open>g__OpenAsync|45_0(Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternalAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternalAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(AsyncEnumerator enumerator, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass33_0`2.<<ExecuteAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
```

But the following attempts to do the same is succeeded and the pool always created with 4 connections

and one more things is that hence created connections gets closed automatically after a while, if i try to call an api which requires some data from the database, the first attempt to execute the query is always fails, and it always succeeds in the second attempt

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<DbContextClass>(options =>
{
    options.UseNpgsql(connectionString,
        options =>
        {
            options.CommandTimeout(15);
            options.EnableRetryOnFailure(2);
        }
        );
});
```

this is my retry strategy.

any help is appreciated

Comment: I have manually closed all connections using
connections.ForEach(connection => { connection.Close(); }); @MitchWheat

Comment: This code isn't initializing any kind of pool, it's leaking connections. The size of the pool is controlled by ADO.NET and NpgSQL through connection string settings. The error may be caused due to network or server issues. If you connect to a shared database, host or a cloud database, there's no guarantee that the database will be up when your site starts

Comment: `have manually closed` should one of those operations fail, all the other connections will remain open. What happens if you *remove* that code *and* the hard-coded timeout in `UseNpgsql`? What's the actual connection string? What happens if you *increase* the default connection timeout?

Comment: Host=localhost;Database=mydb;Username=postgres;Password=password;Timeout=15;Connection Idle Lifetime=86400;Connection Pruning Interval=86400;Keepalive=5;Minimum Pool Size=10;
this is my connection string.
I thought the above code will open some connections and upon closing it Npgsql will keep them in its Pool, I have inspected its Npgsql.PoolManager and i was able to see 4 Npgsql.Connectors initialised inside it @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: Again, what happens if you *remove* all attempts to change the defaults, both in code and the connection string? Where is this code run? On the local machine? Inside Docker or a VM that just started? You won't be able to connect to a database that's still starting up or recovering after a shutdown.

Comment: If i kept everthing default in the connection string and made no attempt to create the pool on startup, upon receiving first api my application fails to establish connection to the database on first try, and since i have implemented retry logic it will try after 15 seconds. As result the api is always taking more than 15 seconds to respond.
my application runs in an ec2 machine and connects to a postgres db in RDS @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: So you *do* try to connect to a remote cloud database that may not be running or scaled down to idle. The database will start the first time you connect. Trying to do that in advance means you'll incur the startup delay earlier. Increase the connection timeout instead

Comment: Since I am using AWS RDS, i am not sure whether it becomes idle after some time. I did not find anything about idle state in the docs. 
Intially my problem was with the APIs getting delayed more than 15 seconds at random. When i logged the connections in the pool i was able to find that the connection pool is empty when the API delay happens. So inorder to fix that at the application startup i try to create 5 connections, so that the connections will be available in the pool. I cannot increase the connection timeout. Is there any way to keep the connections alive? @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: Did you manage to fix the issue yet? What's the Postgres version that you are using?